# Access this from callback inside member function

Tags: javascript, function, this, member

I'm trying to access a class instance from a callback within a member function. This is one example how it could look like:

```
MyClass.prototype.foo = function(){
    var arr = [1, 2, 3];
    arr.forEach(function(element){
        //The next line doesn't work
        //becuase this doesn't reference my MyClass-instance anymore
        this.elements.push(element);
    });
}
```

Here of course I could work with a for Loop (`for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {...}`) but there are situations where I can't.

I found one way to access my `MyClass` instance:

```
MyClass.prototype.foo = function(){
    var arr = [1, 2, 3];
    var myCurrentInstance = this;    //Store temporary reference
    arr.forEach(function(element){
        //Here it works because I use the temporary reference
        myCurrentInstance.elements.push(element);
    });
}
```

This doesn't seem very clean to me. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`forEach` has an optional `thisarg` you can pass after passing it a callback, so this should work:

```
MyClass.prototype.foo = function(){
    var arr = [1, 2, 3];
    var myCurrentInstance = this;    //Store temporary reference
    arr.forEach(function(element){
        //Here it works because I use the temporary reference
        this.elements.push(element);
    }, this);
}
```

Heres the function definition:

```
arr.forEach(callback[, thisArg])
```

Heres the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

### Update

You can always use `bind` to pass the argument, though it doesn;t look prettier IMHO:

```
MyClass.prototype.foo = function(){
    var arr = [1, 2, 3];
    var myCurrentInstance = this;    //Store temporary reference
    var myfunc = function(element){
        //Here it works because I use the temporary reference
        this.elements.push(element);
    }.bind(this);
    myfunc();
}
```

(I know this is a bad example, but it demonstrates what binding does)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But this is `forEach`-specific, right? Is there no General solution? I am looking for something like in Java: `MyClass.this.elements...`

Comment: In Javascript, this is not yet supported. The `super` keyword is introduced in ECMAScript 6, but is not available on many browsers yet. You can always use `bind`, though.

Comment: @somethinghere I guess arrow function can achieve the same thing? Not sure about it...

Comment: @fuyushimoya but again, like the `super`, its support right now is just not there: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Browser_compatibility

Comment: `super` doesn't really have anything to do with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use arrow functions if your environment supports it (or you compile your code from ES6 to ES5):

```
arr.forEach(element => this.elements.push(elements));
```

Inside arrow functions, `this` is resolved in the lexical environment.

See [How to access the correct `this` context inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback) for a comprehensive list of possible solutions.

However, if this is all the code, and `this.elements` is an array, you can just add them without explicitly iterating:

```
this.elements.push.apply(this.elements, arr);
```

Comment: This is interesting but the support is really abysmal at this time. It's a neat technology, but apart from being neat and a demo, thats about it... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Browser_compatibility

Comment: You can use most of the ES6 features today with a transpiler. There is no reason really to hold back...

Comment: Cool. Learning something new every day.

Comment: Have a look at https://babeljs.io.